# Не создается объект класса контроллера?

Tags: php, mvc, composer, router

Я создаю каркас MVC приложения, используя composer и библиотеку AltoRouter Про .htaccess не забыл, все запросы направляю на Index.php, однако когда я хочу обработать маршрут, то у меня не создается экземпляр класса IndexController.
**Ошибка: Uncaught Error: Class 'IndexController' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\routetest\public\index.php:18 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\routetest\public\index.php on line 18**
Я делаю это так:

```
$obj = new $controller();
```

Однако если написать так:

```
$obj = new IndexController();
```

Ошибка пропадает. Не знаю почему так
Вот весь файл index.php

```
    <?php

use routetest\Controllers\IndexController;

require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';


$router = new AltoRouter();
$router->setBasePath('/routetest');


$router->map('GET', '/', 'IndexController#index', 'index');

$match = $router->match();


list($controller, $action) = explode('#', $match['target']);
$obj = new $controller();
```

Comment: вроде бы вывод находится на поверхности - `new $controller` пытается создать `\IndexController`, а не `\routetest\Controllers\IndexController`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.dynamic.php

Comment: Как это исправить? Не могу конкатенировать пространство имен + имя класса

Comment: можете-не можете, но сделать  надо. В чем сложность то?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Импорт выполняется во время компиляции и поэтому не влияет на имена динамических классов, функций или констант.
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.importing.php

Для Динамических классов нужно самостоятельно прописать пространство имён:

```
$namespace = 'routetest\\Controllers\\';
$className = $namespace . $controller;
$obj = new $className;
```